# Design pattern question for maintainability

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I'm not sure if there is a pattern that should be used here but here is the situation:

I have a number of concrete classes that implement an interface:

```
public interface IPerformAction
{
   bool ShouldPerformAction();
   void PerformAction();
}
```

I have another class that checks input to determine if ShouldPerformAction should be execute.  The rub is that new checks are added fairly frequently. The interface for the checking class is defined as follows:

```
public interface IShouldPerformActionChecker
{
   bool CheckA(string a);
   bool CheckB(string b);
   bool CheckC(int c);
   // etc...
}
```

Finally I currently have the concrete classes call each of the checker methods with the data specific to that concrete class:

```
public class ConcreteClass : IPerformAction
{
   public IShouldPerformActionCheck ShouldPerformActionChecker { get; set; }

   public string Property1 { get; set; }
   public string Property2 { get; set; }
   public int Property3 { get; set; }

   public bool ShouldPerformAction()
   {
      return 
         ShouldPerformActionChecker.CheckA(this.Property1) ||
         ShouldPerformActionChecker.CheckB(this.Property2) ||
         ShouldPerformActionChecker.CheckC(this.Property3);
   }

   public void PerformAction()
   {
      // do something class specific
   }
}
```

Now each time I add a new check, I have to refactor the concrete classes to include the new check.  Each concrete class passes different properties to the checking method so subclasses the concrete classes is not an option.  Any ideas on how this could be implemented in a cleaner manner?

Comment: Personally I think your current method is pretty clean.  How many concrete classes are we talking?  Is it really that hard to tweak the necessary concrete classes as new checks come in?  I think it doesn't matter how you cut it up, you're still going to end up with some concrete class you have to tweak.  The only way to avoid this is to do a "CheckAll()" style function somewhere that the concrete classes use.  Overall though, I think the increased performance of not having to tweak is not going to outweigh the mud factor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "CheckA", "CheckB", etc. names, presumably chosen to avoid exposing confidential information, also obfuscate the nature of the relationships between classes, so I'll have to wing it.

However, this is very nearly [double dispatch](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DoubleDispatch), except you are performing conversion of the objects in-between.

EDIT: Try playing the double dispatch pattern "by the book", rather than decomposing the objects mid-dispatch.  To do this, you'd need something like the following:

```
public interface IPerformAction
{
    bool ShouldPerformAction(IShouldPerformActionChecker checker);
    void PerformAction();
}

public interface IShouldPerformActionChecker
{
    bool CheckShouldPerformAction(FloorWax toCheck);
    bool CheckShouldPerformAction(DessertTopping toCheck);
    // etc...
}

public class FloorWax : IPerformAction
{
    public string Fragrance { get; set; }

    // Note that the text of this method is identical in each concrete class,
    // but compiles to call a different overload of CheckShouldPerformAction.
    public bool ShouldPerformAction(IShouldPerformActionChecker checker)
    {
        return checker.CheckShouldPerformAction(this);
    }
}

public class DessertTopping: IPerformAction
{
    public string Flavor { get; set; }

    // Note that the text of this method is identical in each concrete class,
    // but compiles to call a different overload of CheckShouldPerformAction.
    public bool ShouldPerformAction(IShouldPerformActionChecker checker)
    {
        return checker.CheckShouldPerformAction(this);
    }
}

public class ShimmerApplicationChecker : IShouldPerformActionChecker
{
    // handles binding of FloorWax class to required checks
    public bool CheckShouldPerformAction(FloorWax toCheck)
    {
        return CheckAroma(toCheck.Fragrance);
    }

    // handles binding of DessertTopping class to required checks
    public bool CheckShouldPerformAction(DessertTopping toCheck);
    {
        return CheckAroma(toCheck.Flavor);
    }

    // some concrete check
    private bool CheckAroma(string aroma)
    {
        return aroma.Contains("chocolate");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Let's take a step back - why are you using interfaces in the first place? Can a single implementation of `IShouldPerformActionCheck` be shared between multiple implementations of `IPerformAction`? It seems the answer is no, since ICheck must be aware of implementation-specific properties (Property1, Property2, Property3) on the Action in order to perform the check. Therefore the relationship between IAction and ICheck requires more information than the IAction contract can provide to ICheck. It seems your Check classes should be based on concrete implementations that are coupled to the specific type of action they check, like:

```
abstract class CheckConcreteClass
{
    abstract void Check(ConcreteClass concreteInstance);
}
```

Comment: Yes, a single implementation of IShouldPerformCheck could be shared.  It actually performs shared validation rules such as verifying that an IP isn't blocked, an email isn't blocked, or that keywords aren't blocked.  All that matters to IShouldPerformCheck is that the input is specific to the validation rule.  The concrete classes may provide these inputs in different ways.  For instance, keyword checking may include several different properties of the concrete class.

Answer (score 1):

You could consolidate the checks into a single general method that takes an object:

```
public interface IShouldPerformActionChecker
{
   bool Check(object o);
}
```

Then have a list of these checks in your concrete class:

```
public List<IShouldPerformActionCheck> ShouldPerformActionChecker { get; set; }
```

Less type-safe, but more flexible.

Instead of using `IShouldPerformActionCheck` you could look at using [Predicate<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfcke1bz.aspx) delegate, which does roughly the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new `CheckN`, you're going to have to implement it in each of your concrete checker classes anyway, no?

Or are you talking about refactoring your IPerformActions to actually call that check?

Why don't you just have a `CheckAll` that calls everything?

Comment: Each call to CheckN will have data specific to the the concrete class that is calling it.  A CheckAll method could work, but it would still require the concrete class to apply its specific data to it.  The more I think about it the more I'm thinking there is really no way to prevent having to go into each concrete class for each addition.  

I guess one alternative would be a ShouldPerformActionCheckerFactory and the concrete class specific logic is applied there.  I'm not sure if that just muddies the water though.

Comment: If you have to make a class-specific decision as to which data is passed to which method, then you're going to have to tweak each class when you add another check no matter which way you slice it.

Comment: Not necessarily.  See my description of double dispatch.

Comment: If you need to make class-specific decisions, those decisions need to be made *somewhere*.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of have the concrete classes try to check if the action should be performed, there might be a more maintainable way to have arrange these objects.

What if the checker actually implemented IPerformAction, and had an IPerformAction member that it would call if the action should be performed?  That member could either be another checker in the chain, or the actual class that performs the action if all the criteria have been passed?

To do that might require that you refactor slightly, so that the logic to do the action is contained in one class, while the specific data to be used is in another one (kind of like a Command pattern), so that the checkers could do their jobs.

In this way, you could easily add another validation rule, just by putting it into the 'chain' of objects leading to the final action.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
List<IShouldPerformActionChecker> checkers = new List<IShouldPerformActionChecker>();

//... add in each checker to try

foreach(ConcreteClass objectToCheck in checkset) {
   bool isGood = true;
   foreach(IShouldPerformActionChecker checker in checkers) {
      isGood &= checker.DoCheck(objectToCheck.Property);

       if (!isGood) { break; }
   }

   //handle failed check here
}
```